# How to create Eclipse RCP application that behaves like a wizard?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want create a installer by using Eclipse RCP. I need to give the user a wizard-like installer. This means user can do some options then click next. Or they can go back to previous page by click previous. Or they can cancel the installation by clicking cancel.

Here is my problem:
I don't know how to switch between views when clicking "next","previous". I need to create something like WizardPages and i can change between these pages?

I can't use JFace wizard because I'm required not to pop up any dialog.

I'm totally new to Eclipse RCP so please help!
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider whether you actually want/need Eclipse RCP in this context. Eclipse RCP shines in complex applications with an extensive business domain and complex user interface.

An installer wizard, however, is very straightforward and static. I cannot imagine you requiring more than two or three user inputs. Your question is a bit like "*I want to hear beautiful music. How do I program a robot to play the piano?*"

---

It is much easier to limit yourself to using SWT and JFace. Use the JFace `WizardDialog` to make a nice installation wizard. You will find you will have never needed the Eclipse RCP framework.
See http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWizards/article.html for a nice tutorial.

---

If you do think you need the features of the Eclipse RCP runtime framework, I suggest you follow the path below instead:

- Create an RCP application (e.g. the sample 'Mail' application). A class will be created that is the main entry point in your application. This class will launch the Eclipse Workbench. Delete this code, and instead launch the WizardDialog.

A lot of things will not be available, such as menu's, views with drag-and-drop functionality, keybindings, etc. I cannot imagine you will need those things. However, you will benefit from the following Eclipse RCP features:

- Eclipse launch framework. Ability to create a self-contained product including the JRE.
- OSGi framework. Ability to easily add new plugins. Ability to use services, blueprint, etc.
- JFace framework.
- EMF (if you have a very complicated installation wizard)
- All other eclipse plugins, although a lot of them may not work outside of the context of the Eclipse Workbench.

---

If you are *convinced* you need the full Eclipse Workbench, you can always do the following:

- Define a 'base' perspective that is 'locked down'.
- Use a Command to move from one perspective to the other. This will allow you to keep the previous wizard views open in other (hidden) perspectives.
- Use Eclipse Contexts to hide all the standard Eclipse Workbench functionality, menu's, etc.

Since you are new to Eclipse RCP, I do not recommend learning the framework in the particular usecase of an Installation Wizard. You already need good knowledge of Eclipse RCP to be able to hack it this way, and it will not be a clean or nice implementation :-)

Comment: Thanks so much. I finally convince them to allow dialog. Now I can use wizard :)

Comment: I need RCP because this installation tool need to update itself in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "StackLayout" is what you need.